# Calculating similarity in NSStrings

Tags: ios, string, cocoa-touch, similarity

I need to find a way of comparing `NSString`s to get a percent rating of how much two sentences match.

For instance, how similar is the content of this sentence:

```
NSString *firstSentence = @"The first iPhone was released in 2007.";
```

to this sentence:

```
NSString *secondSentence = @"in 2007, the iphone first iphone was released";
```

I've tried to split them up into words and see how many of the words match with the total amount of words and then give a percent out of that -- but that only compares the word I choose, like

```
NSString *oneWord = @"ipone";
if ([oneWord isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
    matchingWords++;
}
```

This doesn't tell me that it contains the same information -- is it just misspelled, or not?

Another idea I had was to check the pronunciation of both words, but that would be better if `oneWord` was "ifone" and not "ipone".

This will sort of work like a plagiarism check.

What approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance.

One implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/1515464

Seems like you could simply compare the strings by calling:

```
- (CGFloat) compareWithString: (NSString *) stringB matchGain:(NSInteger)gain missingCost:(NSInteger)cost;
```

You can then determine the threshold you want through testing.

Comment: So I add those to classes from github and I can use the line of code you provided in another class where it'll do the comparison?

Comment: Also, this line is causing me some problems: @interface NSString (Levenshtein). I need to specify a base class. like : NSObject

Comment: What do you think? @cabellicar123

Comment: Fixed that error by also "adding" Levenshtein.m @cabellicar123

Comment: I can only see stringB in your line, you do you compare stringA with stringB (compare 2 words)? @cabellicar123

Comment: You would call it as so `[stringA compareWithString:stringB...]`.

Comment: Check out the bottom of the gist. It has a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks;) What exactly does "matchGain" and "missingCost" mean? What are those arguments? @cabellicar123

Comment: They change how much to weigh certain components of the algorithm. You can just use the values he uses in the example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm terrible at searching - but what example? :) @cabellicar123

Comment: At the bottom of the gist there is an example. Scroll down.

Comment: I have to be blind or something, but I can't see any example. "compareWithString" only appears 3 times on the page, and none is related to an example as far as I can see and the link leads to a 404-error. See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6hzrimvfxeunrc/Screenshot%202014-08-30%2022.13.28.png?dl=0

Comment: In the compare with word example he uses some values. Use those for compareWithString.

Comment: Oh I see. I tested with 2 sentences and got CGFloat: 0.857143. There was 1 word missing to match the other sentence. What does 0.857143 mean? is it 85.7% correct or something?

Comment: In a sort answer sort of. Read the wiki article for more info (they explain it better than I could)

Answer (score 0):

How about you split your strings into arrays with something like;

```
NSArray *sentenceOne = [firstSentence componentsSeperatedByString:@“ “];
NSArray *sentenceTwo = [secondSentence componentsSeperatedByString:@“ “];
```

Each array is then easily counted to find the number of words in the sentence.
Then iterate through comparing each element of the first array with the second array. You could check forward or backward in the second array, to see if the same word is present, but not necessarily in the same place. A weighted score could be given based on if it was in the same position, later in the sentence, or earlier in the sentence.

If you wanted to split the sentence in characters then you'd use something like

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0;i<[sentence length];i++)
        {
           NSString *character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [sentence characterAtIndex:i]];
            [characters addObject:character];
        }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I've done so far, but that creates problems as it's so precise. If the word is slightly misspelled it wont get triggered. Say "iphone is cool" or "ifone is cool". (where ifone and iphone mean the same) - then the isEqualToString wouldn't get triggered as the meaning is the same but the spelling isn't

Comment: I guess you could also compare at character level. If it was a vowel in the first sentence at that position and a vowel in the second sentence at that position, then you could treat them as "similar". You could even check similar sounding text such as comparing "ph" to "f", for example. It's a hard one. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I definitely see your point, this would be really hard though. Do you think this is a good approach and a solid option that'll work well? If so, do you know how I can split a word up into its characters?

Comment: Is this or the levenshtein distance approach the best in your opinion?

Comment: From looking at the other answers, it could be your best best. With my approach you could end up re-inventing the wheel, which I do a lot! :-)